# Get all combinations of elements of all lengths of 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of chars of some rows and columns like `unsigned char arr[rows][columns]`.

For example, let's assume rows = 10, columns = 10 and the array is filled up like so:

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  

0: l m n

1: v g h k l Z a b d

2: M q r u v g h k l 

3: M Q R Z a b d

4: M Q R d

5: d
```

There is no guarantee all rows and columns are filled up, and unfilled spaces are simply ignored.

I want to construct all possible 'words' of length 1 to max row, so in this case lengths 1 to 6, of all possible character combinations like such:

```
output:
len : 1
l
m
n
len 2:
lv
lg
lh
...
mv
mg
mn
...
len 3:
lvM
lvq
lvr
...
```

Comment: Yet another observation: For len == 2, you have to use all outputs for len == 1 and combining each with all characters of 2nd row. For len == 3, you have to use all outputs for len == 2, and combining each with all characters of 3rd row. And so on. This might be used to reduce repetition. Maybe, it even allows a fix number of nested loops without the need of that odometer approach.

Comment: this is a common combinatorics thing which probably has a name but i don't know it. Anyway generating all of these combinations is like counting in a different base than 10. To make it easy say there were 10 columns and 3 throws. Then if we let the items in the rows have zero-based indices every 3-digit or fewer base 10 number represents one of the combinations e.g. 123 would mean take the item 1 from the first row, item 2 from the second row, and item 3 from the third row. Now it is complicated because the rows can have variable amounts of items but you can just handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement my other idea:

> Yet another observation: For len == 2, you have to use all outputs for len == 1 and combining each with all characters of 2nd row. For len == 3, you have to use all outputs for len == 2, and combining each with all characters of 3rd row. And so on.

And this is what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> input = {
    "lmn",
    "vghk",
    "Mqr"
  };
  std::cout << "output:\n";
  // gather all combinations
  std::vector<std::string> output;
  // first row
  std::cout << "len : 1\n";
  const std::string& row0 = input.front();
  for (char c : row0) {
    output.emplace_back(1, c);
    std::cout << c << '\n';
  }
  // other rows
  for (size_t i = 1, n = input.size(); i < n; ++i) {
    std::cout << "len : " << i + 1 << '\n';
    const std::string& rowI = input[i];
    const std::vector<std::string> outputPrev = std::move(output);
    output.clear();
    for (const std::string& textPrev : outputPrev) {
      for (char c : rowI) {
        output.emplace_back(textPrev + c);
        std::cout << output.back() << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
output:
len : 1
l
m
n
len : 2
lv
lg
lh
lk
mv
mg
mh
mk
nv
ng
nh
nk
len : 3
lvM
lvq
lvr
lgM
lgq
lgr
lhM
lhq
lhr
lkM
lkq
lkr
mvM
mvq
mvr
mgM
mgq
mgr
mhM
mhq
mhr
mkM
mkq
mkr
nvM
nvq
nvr
ngM
ngq
ngr
nhM
nhq
nhr
nkM
nkq
nkr
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bb3f57710ac0af8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursive version of the solution -- recursion based on the fact that the combinations of length `n` are just each item in a row concatenated on to all the combinations of length `n-1` for all items in the row.

Note that `n` in the following is the zero-based index of the last row to include, so if you want all 6 character combinations that means `n` equals 5.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> all_combinations(const std::vector< std::vector <std::string>>& rows, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return rows[0];
    auto n_minus_one_combos = all_combinations(rows, n - 1);
    const auto& row = rows[n];
    std::vector<std::string> n_combos;
    n_combos.reserve(n_minus_one_combos.size() * row.size());
    for (const auto& ch : row) {
        for (const auto& n_minus_one_combo : n_minus_one_combos) {
            n_combos.push_back(n_minus_one_combo + ch);
        }
    }
    return n_combos;
}

void main() {
    std::vector< std::vector <std::string>> rows = {
        {"l", "m", "n"},
        {"v", "g", "h", "k", "l", "Z", "a", "b", "d"},
        {"M","q","r","u","v", "g", "h", "k", "l"},
        {"M","Q","R","Z","a","b","d"},
        {"M","Q","R","d"},
        {"d"}
    };

    for (const auto& combo : all_combinations(rows, 5)) {
        std::cout << combo << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea with the recursion is actually nice. (Too bad that I didn't have it.) ;-)
Nevertheless, your MCVE doesn't produce the expected output. (Have a look at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e73fb643aed20328).) There are also some weaknesses: 1. `void main()` - Per standard `main()` has to have an integral return type. 2. `for (const auto& combo : all_combinations(rows, 5))` Instead of hard-coding the value (`5`), it could be easily computed from `rows.size()` (which is more maintenance-friendly). 3. `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` to store `char`s?

Comment: However, the OP doesn't seem to react. (I took it as a nice riddle to spend my Sunday evening with and had fun to get it running but beyond this I'm not sure whether it was worth the effort.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the way to a good solution is

- to first analyze the requirements and
- then get an understanding of the mathematical background,
- do the appropriate design,
- using adequate C++ containers and elements
- and at the very end, write the code

After analyzing the requirements, we find out that the mathematical background is to build a cartesian product of 2 sets.

The elements in the set are `std::string`s. We start with strings having only one character and build the cartesian product. The result is a strings with 2 characters, containing all possible combinations of the single characters.

For this task, building the cartesian product, is exceptionally simple. It is just a string concatenation of 2 elements. And with a `std::string` we can simply use the '+' operator for string concatention.

So, in C++ we can use 2 nested for loops like so:

```
for (const Element a : elements) 
    for (const Element b : B.elements)
         cartesianProduct.elements.insert( a + b );
```

As a container for our elements, we can use one of the existing "sets" in the STL.

1. `std::set` having unique elements and is ordered
2. `std::mulitset` can have duplicate elements and is ordered
3. `std::unordered_set` having unique elements and is not ordered
4. `std::unordered_mulitset` can have duplicate elements and is not ordered

So, we mayselect any type of set, depending on our wish or requirements.

And since we are in C++ and do object oriented programming, we will wrap everthing in a class (struct) and overwrite 2 operators:

1. `operator *` for creating the cartesian product
2. `operator <<` for simple output

So, if we change something within our class, the outer world will not be influenced. With that we can also use a `std::vector` to store the elements. No big deal at all.

And, for the implementation, we will add a special functionality for building the cartesian product. Normally the product of 2 sets, with at least one set being empty, will result in an empty set. But, because we want to do cartesian products for a whole set of sets, we want to start with an empty set and then build up all following sets in a loop.

And since in our case the cartesian product of 2 elements is a concatenation, so basically an addition, we can live with one set being empty (And a neutral element). Dear all mathematicians: Please show mercy and forgive me for doing that!

With all these preparations, we will build a very simple wrapper class and an even simpler and more intuitive "main" function. Please see one of many possible solutions below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>

using Element = std::string;
using SetImplementation = std::unordered_set<Element>;

// Small wrapper to add additional functionality to our set
struct CSet {

    SetImplementation elements{};

    // Calculate the cartesian product
    CSet operator * (const CSet& B) {

        // Special handling. If one of the sets is empty, we return the other
        if (elements.empty()) return B; if (B.elements.empty()) return *this;

        // The resulting set containing the cartesian product
        CSet cartesianProduct{};
       
        // For all elements in set A and set B
        for (const Element a : elements) for (const Element b : B.elements)

            // For strings, the cartesian product is concatenation
            cartesianProduct.elements.insert( a + b );
        return cartesianProduct;
    }
    // Create the desired output for the set
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const CSet& s) {
        if (not s.elements.empty()) {
            os << "Len: " << s.elements.begin()->size() << '\n';
            std::copy(s.elements.begin(), s.elements.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Element>(os, "\n"));
        }
        return os;
    }
};

// Test data
const std::vector<CSet> testSets{ 
    {{"l", "m", "n"}},
    {{"v", "g", "h", "k", "L", "Z", "a", "b", "d"}},
    {{"M", "q", "r", "u", "v", "g", "h", "k", "l"}},
    {{"M", "Q", "R", "Z", "a", "b", "d"}},
    {{"M", "Q", "R", "d"}},
    {{"d"}} };

// Driver Code
int main() {

    CSet cartesianProduct{};
    CSet& A{ cartesianProduct };

    for (const CSet& B : testSets) {
        cartesianProduct = A * B;
        std::cout << cartesianProduct;
    }
}
```

As said. You may use all kind of different sets. Simply change the using staement at the top, and it will continue to work.

---

And if you prefer to use a `std::vector`, then this is also possible. We will only modify class internals. Outside code stays as is. Please See the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using Element = std::string;
using SetImpl = std::vector<Element>;

struct Set {
    std::vector<Element> elements{};

    Set operator * (const Set& B) {

        if (elements.empty()) return B;
        if (B.elements.empty()) return *this;

        Set cartesianProduct{}; 
        cartesianProduct.elements.resize(elements.size() * B.elements.size());
        auto product{ cartesianProduct.elements.begin() };

        for (const Element a : elements) for (const Element b : B.elements)
            *product++ = a + b;
        return cartesianProduct;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Set& s) {
        if (not s.elements.empty()) {
            os << "Len: " << s.elements[0].size() << '\n';
            std::copy(s.elements.begin(), s.elements.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Element>(os,"\n"));
        }
        return os;
    }
};

std::vector<Set> testSets{ {{"a","b"}}, {{"c"}}, {{"e", "f", "g"}} };

int main() {

    Set cartesianProduct{}, &A{ cartesianProduct };

    for (const Set& B : testSets) {
        cartesianProduct = A * B;
        std::cout << cartesianProduct;
    }
}

#endif



#if 0
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <climits>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    // Loop. unitl the input number is valid
    for (bool numberIsValid{}; not numberIsValid;) {

        // Instruct user on what to do
        std::cout << "\n\nEnter a number (digits only, no leading 0es) that you would like to reverse:\n";

        // Read a number as string and check, if it is valid
        if (std::string numberAsString{}; std::getline(std::cin, numberAsString) and
            not numberAsString.empty() and
            std::all_of(numberAsString.begin(), numberAsString.end(), std::isdigit) and
            not (numberAsString[0] == '0') and
            numberAsString.size() < std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits10)
        {
            // Number is valid
            numberIsValid = true;
            std::cout << "\n\nReverse number is:\t ";
            std::copy(numberAsString.rbegin(), numberAsString.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "\nError: Invalid input\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```